# Curl not working with google translate

Tags: http, curl

Maybe this is a silly question but why can I not access https://translate.google.com. using curl.

It gives me error 401 - forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's forbidden and Google set their servers to not allow you access that way. Most likely it's a mostly javascript page, too, so there's nothing to download that you can use or that they want you to use.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Translate page resricts use based on the user-agent string, presumably to stop you using tools like curl on it directly.

You *can* work around it by setting the user-agent string, e.g.:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' https://translate.google.com
```

but you may run into other problems too, and it's likely against Google's Terms of Service.

A much better suggestion is to use the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) instead.